# Stopping spring task scheduler at runtime by removing the bean definition from context does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I'm using the code below to run a scheduled task. And at runtime I removed this bean from the spring context. Why the task is still not stopped.

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public class MyScheduler {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
    public void schedule() {
        // task here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its work for me:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/scheduler")
public class SchedulerController {

    @Autowired
    AbstractApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler;

    @RequestMapping("/stop")
    @ResponseBody
    public String stop() {
        // scheduler.shutdown();
        BeanDefinitionRegistry factory = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        factory.removeBeanDefinition("MyScheduler");
        return "stoped";
    }
}


@Service("MyScheduler")
@EnableScheduling
public class MyScheduler {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * ?")
    public void schedule() {
        System.out.println("> Running scheduler .... " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

The alternative were to add to the scheduler some 'enable' flag:

```
@Service("MyScheduler")
@EnableScheduling
public class MyScheduler {

    boolean enable = true;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * ?")
    public void schedule() {
        if(enable){
            System.out.println("> Running scheduler .... " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }
}
```

Then it is simple possible to enable and disable the scheduler.